# How to raise error from custom save method in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have defined a custom save method. In this method i want to raise some error if one of the field is empty.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some operation and end up getting self.iot_boxes 
        # this model field (iot_boxes) can be a list full of values or an empty list

        logger.info(f"Selected IOT boxes to be updated {self.iot_boxes}")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Initially `iot_boxes` may or may not be empty
or after some operation it can end up empty during operation in the `save()` method.

How can i display some kind of error on the admin page when the `self.iot_boxes` comes out as empty.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good solution to make validation in save method.

Most views (and specially in django admin) cannot handle a ValidationError in the save method. Your user will get a 500 error...

You have to make this validation in the form and raise ValidationError there.
Then call save method only if the model form data is 'ok for saving'

Comment: what do you mean by validating in form?

Comment: you can raise ValidationError in clean() method of a custom form. or append some Validator on your form fields (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: clean() is not working, I have tried putting the validation in the clean method. This does raise the validation error but in the end it will end up with the traceback page if debug is on and 500 when it is off. I am not using ModelForm here. I am using the same form which gets created by default and my question is related to that.

Comment: `clean()` is the solution for this case. If you are an error, please post code for helping you because it is not the normal behaviour